# i want to ask how to replace local asset using existing data in API

Tags: api, dart

i want to replace assets/1.json to api URL because the required data is in API not local, and how do i change it, i have tried but still getting error.
Thank you

```
static Future<Map<String, DataKuliahModel>> getDataKuliah() async {
    String url = Constant.baseURL;
    String token = await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken();
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4));
    // String responseJson = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/1.json');

    Map<String, DataKuliahModel> finalResult = {};
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
        '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/perwalian/get_paket',
      ),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
    );
    final result = jsonDecode(response)['data'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
    result.forEach((key, value) {
      DataKuliahModel dataKuliah = DataKuliahModel.fromMap(value);
      finalResult.addAll({
        key: dataKuliah,
      });
    });
    return finalResult;
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your API or it's response, but you probably want to pass `response.body` to your `jsonDecode`.

Comment: Can we ask in private chat?
I have a problem but it's a bit long to discuss here